# pod install giving me errors

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I solve such error?

Edit; now I am getting this error

pod install

pod install

```
[Desktop/release/workspace-ios-develop]$ pod install
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/bin/pod (LoadError)
```

My command history responsible for the problem

pastebin.com/6X9BSfvf
line 334 started all the mess \curl -sSL get.rvm.io | bash -s stable; this started it.

Answer (score 0):

in .bash_profile i added GEM_PATH = /user/kh/.gem

And it worked.